# What will happen on the regular Ubuntu forums when Ubuntu One is discontinued?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Will there be a different way to register, because currently the only way to register is through Ubuntu One. Are there other ways TO register? I haven't seen anything about it on Google.

Comment: The original post said `The shutdown will not affect the Ubuntu One single sign on service, the Ubuntu One payment service, or the backend U1DB database service.` http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nothing, as it is the storage service itself going offline, the account sign in and metadata are kept separate and preserved for that very reason